# Regular Expression: Get first word of a sentence if it has more than 3 chars

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that get the first word of a sentence if it has more than 3 characters or the full sentence either.

For example:

```
Hello world -> Hello World
Eat jam -> Eat
```

Thanks!

Comment: does it have to be a regular expression?

Comment: eihter? like an empty string is okay?

Comment: try with this: /^\s*(\w{3,})\b/

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression `^\s*?\w{3,}\b.+`

Comment: and in case not three letters the full sentence... .

Answer (score 1):

Your example takes the first word if it has *less than or equal to* 3 characters and otherwise the complete sentence. But for that requirement you can use

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,3}(?![a-zA-Z])|^.*$
```

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> $re = '^[a-zA-Z]{3}(?![a-zA-Z])|^.*$'
PS> 'Hello world','Eat jam' |%{$_-match $re|Out-null;$Matches}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              Hello world
0                              Eat
```

Comment: Because `\w` is something that vaguely represents the notion of a character usable in identifiers in many programming languages, but is of little to no use when processing text. Or do your words frequently have underscores or digits in them? `\b` is defined in terms of `\w`, so it's equally useless.